# Programmatically create content database in C# (SP 2013)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2013, sitecollection

The goal is to have a web user interface with the option to create new site collections with new Content Database.

With the admin user I can manually in the CA create new Content Databases. I can also create a new site collection in this content database.

The idea was to create an event receiver (C#). If the user adds data to a table, the mentioned actions are to be executed.

Experiments: 
a) Console application - works!

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp2013")) {
  using (SPWeb spWeb = site.OpenWeb()) {
      SPWebApplication elevatedWebApp = spWeb.Site.WebApplication;
        elevatedWebApp.ContentDatabases.Add("sp2013", "WSS_Content_80_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyymmddhhMMss"), null, null, 10, 15, 0);
    }
}
```

b) Event Receiver - Only create site collections works, creation of content databases does not work! Error: Access Denied.

c) Web Service - Does not work! Error: Access Denied.

So, why do I get the error Access Denied when I can create site collections, but only content databases creation not go?

Finally I executed PS Script - but this also doesn´t work.

```
# AUTHOR: Paul Kotlyar
# CONTACT: unclepaul84@gmail.com
# DESCRIPTION: sets an option on content web service that allows updating of SP Administration objects such as SPJobDefinition from content web applications
function Set-RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied-False()
{
    # load sharepoint api libs
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") > $null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration") > $null

  # get content web service
 $contentService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
  # turn off remote administration security
 $contentService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied = $false
  # update the web service
 $contentService.Update()
}
```

Maybe somebody knows a solution?

I asked the same question in [Stackexchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132414/programmatically-create-content-database-in-c-sp-2013).

Comment: For any Access Denied error: what user/identity is performing what operation on what thing? Then look at the permissions associated with that thing for the operation for that user/identity. Remember the server side is not the same as the client.

Comment: The user is farm admin also in the Web Application User Policy with Full Control rights. Tried to run code with RunWithElevatedPrivelages but didn´t work.

Comment: "The user": which one? The client or the server? It is the server that is executing these operations and it is that user which needs access.

Comment: The client user is farm admin.

Comment: The client user is irrelevant (probably), the server is performing the operations; therefore the server needs the access.

Comment: When I run the code with RunWithElevatedPrivileges, the code current SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name is farm admin (server side), but still access denied. What to do anymore?

Comment: Check that the web app is impersonating the client. (Eg. file operations can be monitored with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) to check the identity being used)

Comment: If you runwithelevated it only elevates the permissions to the app pool account, Check what your app pool account is for the web app. I believe that the app pool shouldn't have farm access, Have you tried removing the runwith elevated but logging in to sharepoint as your SP Farm account?

Comment: Yes. I tried this with an user that is in the farm admin accounts group. Can I do this (create content database) somehow else - without changing user permissions?

Comment: Solved it with an Farm Application page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a permissions problem, but not for clients account. The client user is irrelevant. The problem is that for content database creation your code need farm administrator privileges. However, running code with elevated privileges is insufficient, because when you execute code in this way, SharePoint impersonate with application pool user of correspondent web application.

If the app pool user for "http://sp2013" do not have farm admin privileges, you cannot create content database with an event receiver (maybe for this reason you have an Access Denied error for your event receiver and your webservice code). The problem is giving farm admin privileges to an app pool or service user it's a very bad idea.

I recommend to you implement this solution as timer job. You can create a SharePoint farm solution, and make a timer job, because normally timer jobs are executed with a farm admin account. In this way, you could create a content database.